# State is persisting when pressing back/forward on Safari browser (react-router-dom)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently using Reactjs and I've come into a issue with state management for some reason when pressing the back/forward button on Safari browser it's keeping the components exactly the same has they previously was but the URL will update.

Note: this is also happening when swiping on iPhone.

I can resolve this issue with the following:

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
};
```

I'm looking for a different solution as this seems to be hacky and does a slight double refresh and it is noticeable when it happens.

Library being used for router: react-router-dom

React Dom Rendering:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <AuthProvider>
        <IntercomProvider autoBoot={true} appId={''}>
            <App />
        </IntercomProvider>
    </AuthProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Switch Routing:

```
import React from "react";

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <React.Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
            <Router>
                <ReactNotification />

                <React.StrictMode>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

                        {singleRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
                        ))}

                        {boilerAdviceRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
                        ))}

                        {boilerQuotesRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
                        ))}

                        <Route path="*">
                            <Error />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                    <GoogleAnalyticsLocation />
                </React.StrictMode>
            </Router>
        </React.Suspense>
    );
}

const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => {
    return (
        <Route
            exact={route.exact || undefined}
            path={route.path}
            render={(props) => (
                // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
                <route.component {...props} />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

**Update:**

After research, I can't find any solutions other than refreshing the page. I've had to add callbacks to all my action buttons to reset state just before page is redirected, this is not the best solution but at least it is resolved until someone comes up with an actual answer.

Comment: Could your share some code of where your routing is happening?

Comment: @sschwei1 - it's only happening when you press the browsers back button, it's fine if you redirect with an `a` tag

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito - I've changed the router to react-router-dom and it's same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the `import`/definition for `Router`, `Switch`, `Route`?

Comment: @edemaine - updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the re-use of keys within siblings, whereas [keys need to be unique among siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796342/react-key-uniqueness-on-different-elements).  Does the following work?

```js
                        {singleRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={"s"+i} {...route} />
                        ))}

                        {boilerAdviceRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={"a"+i} {...route} />
                        ))}

                        {boilerQuotesRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={"q"+i} {...route} />
                        ))}
```