# In a nested map function in Render function in React, are values of key attribute need to be unique among both outer and inner loop?

Tags: reactjs

According to the official documentation of React, key attributes are needed to let React know if any element in the array is added, removed, or modified.
So supposed I have a nested for loop in a render function.

Supposed we have

```
parents.map((each, index)=>{
    return(
        <div key={index}>
             each.map((number, i)=>{
                 return <Child number={number} key={i} />
              }) 
        </div>     
    )
});
```

Both the parent div elements and the Child components have key attribute to identify them, and they are all in an array. However, do all the values of the key attributes among the div and the Child component need to be unique? None the less, they are from different loops. In case each item inside the parents array is also an array, and all of these arrays have a same length. Eventually, the "key" value will be duplicated, such as

```
const parents = [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

We will have

```
<div key={0}>
    <Child number={1} key={0} />
    <Child number={2} key={1} />
</div> 
<div key={1}>
    <Child number={2} key={0} />
    <Child number={3} key={1} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need just unique keys in each map,
there is not any problem if your inner map elements have same keys.
but elements of one map should not have same keys.

please read this link:
[React Key uniqueness on different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796342/react-key-uniqueness-on-different-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @[**Rongeegee**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6707111/rongeegee),

I read lots of articles about that when I was doing **react**. In my opinion, **key** in React should **unique** but not globally **unique** it should **unique** when you render child elements because it's to detect the state of your elements when you modify or delete or you change it. It's also useful to create dynamic elements, resetting elements when their keys change, it's actually all about to **identity** the elements `which in turn leads to better performance`. I'm not sure, but I see many times. If You are not given any **keys** to React then, it uses by default the index in the array. That why lots of people like to use some package for **key** for uniqueness like [**uudi**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). Because when you change array elements it changes its **key** and **value** like `0:apple,1:pineapple` then if you delete **apple** then it's look like this `0:pineapple`.

Also, I suggest you to read this discussion [**github-discussion-about-key**](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1342#issuecomment-39230939)

```js
parents.map((each, index)=>{
    return(
        <div key={index}>
            each.map((number, i)=>{
                  return <Child number={number} key={i} />
              }) 
        </div>     
    )
});
```

In my opinion, The above example of yours, have no problem. You can do that. But as I wrote, when you change your **parent** array element, it changes the **index** of your **value** of your child. Same thing happened with child if you change the element of child.

Answer (score -1):

In here You can do this kind of a thing. I change the code little bit and put in the sandbox.[See the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-key-issue-t31hqz).Then you can play with the code.

I will put here the code here,if link broken,others can't view this.

```
export default function App() {
  let val = 0;
  const parents = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3]
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {parents.map((each, index) => {
        val = val + 1;
        return (
          <div key={val}>
            {val}
            {each.map((number, i) => {
              val = val + 1;
              return <div key={val}> {val}</div>;
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```